# Regular expression for my password policy

Tags: c#, .net, regex

My password strength criteria is as below :

- Character length: 8 -> 24
- Contains least 3 of following types:

  - Uppercase letter [A-Z]
  - Lowercase letter [a-z]
  - Numeric [0-9]
  - Special character ~`!@#$%^&*()-_=+[{]}\|;:'"<,>.?/

Can anyone help me to make regular expression and explain. Thanks.

Comment: do you need to use a regular expression?

Comment: Hint: you're gonna need look-aheads. Also: would personally not use RegEx for this.

Comment: If my rule can be written by regex, I can use it with javascript as good as .net C#.

Comment: @LuLu Yes, this requires lookaheads mainly (if you're using only one regex, you don't if you are using several), which is supported by both JS and C#.

Answer (score 0):

It would be very difficult to do in one regex. Personally, I'd check for each case separately and count if you've got three matches. It would be easier to read and maintain.

So match [A-Z] then [a-z] then [0-9] and finally [~`!@#$%^&*()-_=+[{]}\|;:'"<,>.?/]

If you end up with a match in three of the tests that's success.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Regex:

```
(?=.{8,24})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*[~`!@#\$%\^&\*()_=\+[{\]}\|;:'"<,>\.\?/]).*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/xq_nL0QcOZ3b49CV)